# Differential Backup approx equals to Full Backup [IN SIZE]

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, metadata, database-backups

I'm currently using *SQL Server 2005* for handling data/records in my application and usually use default(full) mode for DB backup. Recently, I switched its backup mode to differential to get rid of excessive size/time which ideally full backup operation takes.

However, I shocked to see newly created differential backups of size merely less than **100-150 MB** than its full backup which means whenever DB restore is required, it will double my workload by restoring both(full and differential) backups of same size and take almost double the time. I didn't understand what exactly is considered before differential backup initiates.

If I say, I have a 3 tables with 1000 records and out of which only 150 records added/updated today after taking a full backup. So how does differential backups decide what to consider to backup exactly? I don't think SQL internally put a where clause on tables and filter out updated records only or so? Don't know probably these things get decided at metadata level but how?

As per backup script is considered, it's perfect. See below.

*BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase] TO DISK = ''C:\DB\MyDatabaseDiffertialBackup.diff'' WITH DIFFERENTIAL, INIT*

Answer (score 0):

You need to first understand SQL backup types and recovery models. For an efficient point in time recovery, a proper backup plan should consist of:-

1. Full backup (this can be done on a weekly basis or in every 3-4 days).
2. Differential or Incremental backup (can be done on a daily basis).
3. Log Backup (every 15 minutes).

You should have at least one full backup in a week (mostly during off load hours when the load on the database in minimal), followed by daily incremental backups and log backups. In case if database restoration is needed, all you need to do is restore the latest full backup, followed by the latest differential backup, followed by the latest transaction log backup. Relying on only differential backup for DB restoration is not a best practice.

Again the change in metadata for differential backup is decided on the basis of the previous full backup being taken. A differential backup is not independent and it must be based on the latest full backup of the data. That means there should have a full backup as a base. A differential backup contains only the data that has changed since the differential base.